# Can we fully ionize an atom by annhilating its electrons with a positron beam?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, ionization-energy, positronium

I am unable to digest research papers on this topic so I am asking here. Can an atom be fully ionized by a positron beam through positron-electron annhilation? What are the limitations of this process and what are some factors one must consider ( like minimum energy/momentum etc) when conducting such experiment for fessibility?

Comment: You don’t need antimatter to ionize atoms. Why are you interested in doing it in this way?

Comment: Uhm one thing I was trying to see if this idea works and secondly I thought maybe it will be easier to ionize very stable atoms like noble gases, lead , gold etc completely and perhaps with lower energy requirements than the conventional way

Comment: Fully stripping ions is actually really easy, far far easier than producing positrons in the first place.

Comment: *lower energy requirements* Compare the binding energy of an inner electron of gold to the energy required to make an electron-positron pair.